# Removing words using RegExp

Tags: javascript, regexp-substr

I have a string with tags.
`"<blue>Hello, <red>world</red>!</blue>"`. And I have to get this string without tags using RegExp. 
I wrote this code, but I think that it can be easier. 
`str.split('<red>').join('').split('</red>').join('').split('</blue>').join('').split('<blue>').join('');`

 Please, help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.replace(/<\/?(red|blue)>/g, "")`:

```js
console.log( "<blue>Hello, <red>world</red>!</blue>".replace(/<\/?(red|blue)>/g, "") )
```

If you want to match also case insensitive versions of the tags, you just need to insert `i` after `/g`. This will not work with attributes or spaces before or after the tag name. If you need it, comment on this answer and I will edit it.

Comment: Yes and no. This code removes everything in <>, so if I have `"<blue><Hello>, <red>world</red>!</blue>"`, the code will output `, world`. I only have to remove tags <blue>, </blue>, <red>, </red>.

Comment: Man, thank a lot. You are the best. It is what I want

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var s = "<blue>Hello, <red>world</red>!</blue>";
s.replace(/<.*?>/g, " ");
Result -> " Hello,  world ! "
```